# Ubuntu not being displayed in the windows boot manager

Tags: usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

I download an iso file and installed Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB , i had windows -7 installed already on C drive , i installed ubuntu on E drive (sda5) , after the installation completed , it asked to restart , then i restarted , but the machine automatically loads windows-7 , ubuntu doesn't show up , help me out please !

Okk , my machine doesn't support CD's , so can i do this boot repair without any Live CD !

Comment: Windows boot manager will never show Ubuntu

Comment: @Anwar The answer on that one is complicated though... :S

Answer (score 1):

Try with Boot Repair!

### 1 - Live CD

First, you'll need to boot from a Ubuntu Live CD.

### 2 - Install the Grub bootloader

To install the Grub bootloader, follow these steps.

Open Terminal from the Live CD, and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

After a few seconds, Boot Repair's main window will open.

Click on `Recommended repair`.

### You're done!

Reboot to test everything out.

If everything went well, you should be up and running now.

Once Ubuntu is loaded, you may open Terminal and issue the following command to automatically detect Windows and add it to Grub's menu, if it isn't there already.

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

#### Glossary

> **[Bootloader](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/telux/lin-club_files/linux-boot/slide0002.htm)**: a piece of code that runs before any operating system is running. A bootloader is used to boot other operating
>   systems. Each operating system usually has its own bootloader.
>
> **[GRUB (*Grand Unified Bootloader*)](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/definition/GRUB-GRand-Unified-Bootloader)**: a bootloader package developed to support multiple operating systems and allow the user to select among them during boot-up. It is Ubuntu's default bootloader.
>
> **[Command, command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: the traditional Unix environment , where you type commands to tell the computer what to do.
>
> **[Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: an application that allows you to access the command line. Open it by hitting its keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>.