# Ubuntu 11.10 bootloader doesn't start windows 7

Tags: boot, grub2, bootloader

I just installed ubuntu 11.10 alongside with Windows 7. 
Ubuntu starts and work fine.
Instead, when i click on the last option:

```
windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)
```

the bootloader reload itself and doesn't start windows 7!
So now i can only use ubuntu!
For me ubuntu is good etc, but i like also to use windows if possible... can you help me?

Here's my Boot Info Script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5655022/

Comment: i just follow the second point of this procedure: 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/194071/ubuntu-not-being-displayed-in-the-windows-boot-manager

it told me to repair the boot sector sda1 using instrument like testdisk, it give me also this beautifull document: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5655022/

Comment: Hmm looks like you have Wubi installed.  Windows might cause problems if you have Wubi and a full Ubuntu installation on the same computer.

Comment: Also, try running Boot Repair from a Live Ubuntu CD or USB.  It might fix your problems :)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: is the same, doesn't work, it's wise for you try to destroy wubi folder?
this is the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5659502/

Comment: this is my http://pastebin.com/HgNFhN3Y grub.cfg

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu open a terminal and run

sudo update-grub

The system should regenerate all bootable kernels and chain loading boot partitions

A word of note, it is very possible that grub is fine but the Wondow boot sector is broken. Grub chainloads the Wondow bootstrapper.

you may need to run a repair from Wondow disc/media so its the only bootable system then use the ubuntu livecd/disc to re-install grub

Comment: Done some further research. You csn also try a utility called boot-repair.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: thanks, Emerson just suggested me to do so...i will tray to adjust the win boot loader by win 7 cd.....